# finding duplicates in a table 

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL - How can I remove duplicate rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/sql-how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows)

Hello all

How I can Write following query .

I have a table `Trace`  and I want to get all lines there where `ID` columns and `MC` columns combinations are appear more then once.

for example all lines where `ID = 2 and MC = 11` appear more then once .

Thanks

Comment: Asked many many times before. http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+find+duplicates+database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group on `ID, MC`, and use `having` to select combinations that occur more than once:

```
select  ID
,       MC
from    Trace
group by
        ID
,       MC
having  count(*) > 1
```

Comment: I want also to see a column callen TimeDone, how i can do it here ?

Comment: Add `, Min(TimeDone) AS MinTimeDone, Max(TimeDone) AS MaxTimeDone` to the select clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Trace T1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT ID, MC
  FROM Trace T2
  GROUP BY ID, MC
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) T22
ON T22.ID = T1.ID
AND T22.MC = T1.MC
```